# Prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n!(3n)!}{((2n)!)^2}(\frac{16}{27})^n\sin(nx)$ diverges

Tags: calculus

Prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n!(3n)!}{((2n)!)^2}(\frac{16}{27})^n\sin(nx)$ diverges for $x\in(0,2\pi)$.

Comment: @MichaelTong Thanks. I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Stirling's formula, the coefficients are asymptotic to $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. The problem reduces to the divergence of $\sum \sin(nx)$, which is divergent since the terms do not go to zero.